# How to dictate a Non-English text on an English Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm using an English Windows 7 with speech recognition working fine if I'm dictating in English.

I would like to dictate a letter in German. I don't need further features that let you use your computer without a mouse, I want to dictate my letter.

If I just start speaking German the Windows speech recognition software just gives me English gibberish.

When I set the Speech Recognition to "German" in the Speech Properties dialog, I get the error message:

Speech Recognition could not start because the language configuration is not supported.
The recognizer language must match the language of the user interface.  Please change the recognizer language in the Speech Recognition control panel under Advanced Options.

This error message doesn't help me, because it tells me that I either need to change my system language or the language I want to dictate. But that's not what I want.

How can I dictate in German on my PC with the English version of Windows 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the German recognizer, then you'll have to set your OS language to German (e.g. with **[Vistalizator](http://www.sevenlizator.com/index.html)**).

if you don't want to change the system language, then you'll have to resort to 3rd party software (e.g. **[Dragon Naturally Speaking](http://shop.nuance.de/store/nuanceeu/de_DE/DisplayProductDetailsPage/productID.115531300)**)

Comment: So apparently even 11 years later this is still the case for Windows 10, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's possible.  It sounds like you need to install the Windows MUI Pack before being able to change the language in the Speech Recognition software.