# Windows 8.1 speech recognition in different languages

Tags: windows-8.1, language, speech-recognition

[A similar question has already been asked, but for Windows 7, and it was a while ago.](https://superuser.com/q/87577)

I wanted to dictate in French and Slovene, as well as in English. Is it true that I can't switch the language to dictate in without first switching the language of the user interface and log out and back in for the change to take effect?

I would like to have user interface in English, but be able to dictate in other languages without closing and reopening everything every time I switch language and without getting baffled by user interface's language - is that possible without using 3rd party software?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise it because there was some talk about 3rd party software in other questions/answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a work-around for using Windows Speech Recognition in a language that is different from your UI language. Read here: [Windows 8 Speech Recognition Language](https://superuser.com/questions/475926/windows-8-speech-recognition-language). But the linked answer only concerns

There are two caveats:

1. It does not say that it would work with speech recognition language combinations other than US-English/UK-English.
2. For it to work Windows Speech Recognition would have to be available in your language. Slovene is not on the list of available languages on this site: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dictate-text-speech-recognition#1TC=windows-7. Both this Microsoft site and the [Wikipedia entry for Windows Speech Recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Speech_Recognition#Overview_and_features) state that Windows Speech Recognition is only available in these languages: [image: available Windows Speech Recognition languages]

To the best of my knowledge, the only speech recognition in Slovene and a number of other Slavonic languages currently availble is from Google and works in Google Docs, where you go to Tools and then Speech Input. For a complete list of languages read here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/4492226?hl=en. You'd have to copy and paste from there.

[image: excerpt from speech recognition languages in Google Docs]

Note that punctuation won't currently work in most languages other than these: 
[image: Punctuation in speech recognition Google Docs].

I'd recommend using a seldom used word and the search and replace it.